# How to fetch a specific IP via vmware_guest_info?

Tags: ansible, vmware

I use vmware_guest_info: to get the DHCP address for my VMs. The problem is that after I have configured several static IP's, the **guest.ipAddress** is changed from the DHCP address, which is usually the first network adapter, to a randomly configured static IP:

```
---

- name: Gather a virtual machine info
  vmware_guest_info:
    hostname: '{{ vsphere_host }}'
    username: '{{ vsphere_user }}'
    password: '{{ vsphere_password }}'
    validate_certs: false
    datacenter: "{{ vsphere_datacenter }}"
    name: "{{ hostname }}"
    schema: vsphere
    properties:
      - guest.ipAddress
  retries: 60
  delay: 10
  until: gather_vm_info.instance.guest.ipAddress is not none
  register: gather_vm_info
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Gather a virtual machine info
  vmware_guest_info:
    hostname: '{{ vsphere_host }}'
    username: '{{ vsphere_user }}'
    password: '{{ vsphere_password }}'
    validate_certs: false
    datacenter: "{{ vsphere_datacenter }}"
    name: "{{ hostname }}"
    schema: vsphere
    properties:
      - guest.ipAddress
  retries: 60
  delay: 10
  until: gather_vm_info.instance.guest.ipAddress != "0.0.0.0"
  register: gather_vm_info
  delegate_to: localhost

- debug: var=gather_vm_info.instance.guest.ipAddress

- debug: var=gather_vm_info

- name: "Update host_var with new IP Address"
  set_fact: 
    ansible_host: "{{ gather_vm_info.instance.guest.ipAddress }}"
    ansible_hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
```

This is what I get:

```
ok: [1-Europe-ECV-Site2] => 
  gather_vm_info.instance.guest.net:
  - _vimtype: vim.vm.GuestInfo.NicInfo
    connected: true
    deviceConfigId: -1
    dnsConfig: null
    ipAddress:
    - fe80::fc70:f8ff:fe15:ae75
    ipConfig:
      _vimtype: vim.net.IpConfigInfo
      autoConfigurationEnabled: null
      dhcp: null
      ipAddress:
      - _vimtype: vim.net.IpConfigInfo.IpAddress
        ipAddress: fe80::fc70:f8ff:fe15:ae75
        lifetime: null
        origin: null
        prefixLength: 64
        state: unknown
    macAddress: fe:70:f8:15:ae:75
    netBIOSConfig: null
    network: null
  - _vimtype: vim.vm.GuestInfo.NicInfo
    connected: true
    deviceConfigId: -1
    dnsConfig: null
    ipAddress:
    - fe80::dc8b:91ff:fefe:66dd
    ipConfig:
      _vimtype: vim.net.IpConfigInfo
      autoConfigurationEnabled: null
      dhcp: null
      ipAddress:
      - _vimtype: vim.net.IpConfigInfo.IpAddress
        ipAddress: fe80::dc8b:91ff:fefe:66dd
        lifetime: null
        origin: null
        prefixLength: 64
        state: unknown
    macAddress: de:8b:91:fe:66:dd
    netBIOSConfig: null
    network: null
  - _vimtype: vim.vm.GuestInfo.NicInfo
    connected: true
    deviceConfigId: -1
    dnsConfig: null
    ipAddress:
    - fe80::f8ea:c4ff:fe90:99e2
    ipConfig:
      _vimtype: vim.net.IpConfigInfo
      autoConfigurationEnabled: null
      dhcp: null
      ipAddress:
      - _vimtype: vim.net.IpConfigInfo.IpAddress
        ipAddress: fe80::f8ea:c4ff:fe90:99e2
        lifetime: null
        origin: null
        prefixLength: 64
        state: unknown
    macAddress: fa:ea:c4:90:99:e2
    netBIOSConfig: null
    network: null
  - _vimtype: vim.vm.GuestInfo.NicInfo
    connected: true
    **deviceConfigId: 4000**
    dnsConfig: null
    ipAddress:
    - 192.168.0.35
    - fe80::250:56ff:fe91:c8c0
    ipConfig:
      _vimtype: vim.net.IpConfigInfo
      autoConfigurationEnabled: null
      dhcp: null
      ipAddress:
      - _vimtype: vim.net.IpConfigInfo.IpAddress
        ipAddress: 192.168.0.35
        lifetime: null
        origin: null
        prefixLength: 16
        state: preferred
      - _vimtype: vim.net.IpConfigInfo.IpAddress
        ipAddress: fe80::250:56ff:fe91:c8c0
        lifetime: null
        origin: null
        prefixLength: 64
        state: unknown
```

It looks like that VMWare assigned **deviceConfigId: 4000** for the first Network Interface, but how can I access it on my Playbook?

```
debug: var=gather_vm_info.instance.guest.net[3].ipAddress[0]-?????
```

EDIT:

Can somebody explain, why vSphere register the IP address correctly for some VM's as **guest.ipAddress** and sometimes you have to get it as **gather_vm_info.instance.hw_eth0.ipaddresses**.

This would be fine, but in this example you can see that the IPAddress is only registered as **gather_vm_info.instance.hw_eth0.ipaddresses** and you don't get it as **hw_eth0.ipaddresses**???

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [1-USA-ECV-Site8] => 
  gather_vm_info:
    changed: false
    failed: false
    instance:
      annotation: Silver Peak Systems ECV
      current_snapshot: null
      customvalues: {}
      guest_consolidation_needed: false
      guest_question: null
      guest_tools_status: guestToolsRunning
      guest_tools_version: '10341'
      hw_cluster: null
      hw_cores_per_socket: 1
      hw_datastores:
      - Datastore2
      hw_esxi_host: 51.89.43.64
      hw_eth0:
        addresstype: assigned
        ipaddresses: null <<-- IP Address is missing!?
        label: Network adapter 1
        macaddress: 00:50:56:91:55:12
        macaddress_dash: 00-50-56-91-55-12
        portgroup_key: null
        portgroup_portkey: null
        summary: Management
      hw_eth1:
        addresstype: assigned
        ipaddresses: null
        label: Network adapter 2
        macaddress: 00:50:56:91:26:a1
        macaddress_dash: 00-50-56-91-26-a1
        portgroup_key: null
        portgroup_portkey: null
        summary: 1-MPLS
      hw_eth2:
        addresstype: assigned
        ipaddresses:
        - 10.8.10.1
        - fe80::250:56ff:fe91:361d
        label: Network adapter 3
        macaddress: 00:50:56:91:36:1d
        macaddress_dash: 00-50-56-91-36-1d
        portgroup_key: null
        portgroup_portkey: null
        summary: 1-Site8
      hw_eth3:
        addresstype: assigned
        ipaddresses: null
        label: Network adapter 4
        macaddress: 00:50:56:91:b7:ce
        macaddress_dash: 00-50-56-91-b7-ce
        portgroup_key: null
        portgroup_portkey: null
        summary: 1-Site8
      hw_eth4:
        addresstype: assigned
        ipaddresses: null
        label: Network adapter 5
        macaddress: 00:50:56:91:68:73
        macaddress_dash: 00-50-56-91-68-73
        portgroup_key: null
        portgroup_portkey: null
        summary: 1-Site8
      hw_eth5:
        addresstype: assigned
        ipaddresses:
        - fe80::250:56ff:fe91:b5c8
        label: Network adapter 6
        macaddress: 00:50:56:91:b5:c8
        macaddress_dash: 00-50-56-91-b5-c8
        portgroup_key: null
        portgroup_portkey: null
        summary: 1-Site8
      hw_eth6:
        addresstype: assigned
        ipaddresses: null
        label: Network adapter 7
        macaddress: 00:50:56:91:83:ab
        macaddress_dash: 00-50-56-91-83-ab
        portgroup_key: null
        portgroup_portkey: null
        summary: 1-Site8
      hw_files:
      - '[Datastore2] 1-USA-ECV-Site8/1-USA-ECV-Site8.vmx'
      - '[Datastore2] 1-USA-ECV-Site8/1-USA-ECV-Site8.nvram'
      - '[Datastore2] 1-USA-ECV-Site8/1-USA-ECV-Site8.vmsd'
      - '[Datastore2] 1-USA-ECV-Site8/vmware.log'
      - '[Datastore2] 1-USA-ECV-Site8/1-USA-ECV-Site8.vmdk'
      - '[Datastore2] 1-USA-ECV-Site8/1-USA-ECV-Site8_1.vmdk'
      hw_folder: /OVH/vm
      hw_guest_full_name: Other 4.x or later Linux (64-bit)
      hw_guest_ha_state: null
      hw_guest_id: other4xLinux64Guest
      hw_interfaces:
      - eth0
      - eth1
      - eth2
      - eth3
      - eth4
      - eth5
      - eth6
      hw_is_template: false
      hw_memtotal_mb: 4096
      hw_name: 1-USA-ECV-Site8
      hw_power_status: poweredOn
      hw_processor_count: 2
      hw_product_uuid: 4211ed87-aa18-53bb-a983-7aff188b115a
      hw_version: vmx-14
      instance_uuid: 5011fd96-b512-e3d1-d6f0-ac58201e75db
      ipv4: 192.168.0.212 <<-- IP Address is only assigned here!?
      ipv6: null
      module_hw: true
      moid: vm-2296
      snapshots: []
      vimref: vim.VirtualMachine:vm-2296
      vnc: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP Address of the first interface can get through the hw_eth0 property of the vmware_guest_info module result.
Here's the sample playbook.

```yaml
---
- name: Example Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    hostname: test_vm2
  tasks:
    - name: Gather a virtual machine info
      vmware_guest_info:
        hostname: '{{ vsphere_host }}'
        username: '{{ vsphere_user }}'
        password: '{{ vsphere_password }}'
        validate_certs: false
        datacenter: "{{ vsphere_datacenter }}"
        name: "{{ hostname }}"
      register: gather_vm_info

    - name: Display the first interface set IP Address of a virtual machine
      debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ gather_vm_info.instance.hw_eth0.ipaddresses
            | map('ipaddr', 'ipv4')
            | select('!=', false)
            | list
            | first
          }}
```

The hw_eth0 is the interface information of a virtual machine have.
If you want to get the second interface IP Address, change from hw_eth0 to hw_eth1.
The above playbook uses the ipaddr filter in getting only ipv4 address.
So it needs to install netaddr library.

```
(venv)$ pip install netaddr
```

By the way, the following playbook can be possible to get the first interface IP Address too.

```yaml
---
- name: Example Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
    hostname: test_vm2
  tasks:
    - name: Gather a virtual machine info
      vmware_guest_info:
        hostname: '{{ vsphere_host }}'
        username: '{{ vsphere_user }}'
        password: '{{ vsphere_password }}'
        validate_certs: false
        datacenter: "{{ vsphere_datacenter }}"
        name: "{{ hostname }}"
        schema: vsphere
        properties:
          - guest.net
      register: gather_vm_info

    - name: Set device_config_ids variable
      set_fact:
        device_config_ids: >-
         {{ device_config_ids | default([])
           + [item.deviceConfigId]
          }}
      loop: "{{ gather_vm_info.instance.guest.net }}"

    - name: Display the first interface set IP Address of a virtual machine
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1.ipAddress.0 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ device_config_ids | sort | first }}"
        - "{{ gather_vm_info.instance.guest.net }}"
      when:
        - item.0 | int == item.1.deviceConfigId
```

Comment: Thanks sky_joxerxx! They are really brilliant! Can you explain to me what it really does here?

  {{ gather_vm_info.instance.hw_eth0.ipaddresses
            | map('ipaddr', 'ipv4')
            | select('!=', false)
            | list
            | first
          }}

Comment: I just edited my first question, maybe you can help me to find the root cause, because I can't use your approach for all VM's :(

Comment: It is using filters to get the ipv4 address. In the first filter, does evaluation the ipv4 address using the ipaddr. In the second filter, exclude the ipv6 address using the select. This state is an object, so it needs to cast to the list type. And finally, get the first element in the list.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but do you know the reason, why vSphere register the IP address correctly for some VM's as guest.ipAddress and sometimes you have to get it as gather_vm_info.instance.hw_eth0.ipaddresses as edited in my original question?

Comment: The guest.ipAddress is IP address of VM displaying on vCenter.
Displayed IP Address would be one of them if it was set multiple IPs.
If you want to confirm whether an IP address has been set for any of the interfaces, I think to use the guest.ipAddress.
If you have already decided on an IP address of an interface you want to get, I recommend use hw_ethX.